# Rank and nullility of this matrix and $x_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If I have reduced a matrix to the following to find the nullspace:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right] $$

I can see that $x_2 = 0$ and so does $x_3$. I'm thinking that $x_1=0$ too, but I cannot see this in this matrix. The rank of this matrix is supposed to be the number of pivot columns and the nullility the number of free variables. But i'm thinking this matrix is tricking me somehow.

Does it have rank 2? I cannot see any free variables and I'm still left wondering about $x_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you translate your matrix to equations, the equations say nothing about $x_1$. So, $x_1$ is the free variable.

Comment: Ahh, so free variables can be on the left of the pivot also?

Comment: Yes, they can be.

Comment: Ok, thank you @S.Venkataraman

Answer (score 1):

It has rank2, that means that X1 is free.
You can watch it as a system with:

```
x2 = 0;
x3 = 0;
0x1 = 0;
```

General rule is that if the rank of the matrix is less than the number of row you have `n_row - rank` free variables.